# Why does arraylist.contains() not work?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that I am filling with the things I print to make sure I don't repeat the same String. I am using the .contains() method to check:

```
if(!outputted.contains(string)){etc...}
```

I ran the debugger on Eclipse when it still printed repeats, and I saw that even when the ArrayList does hold the String, it still reads the if statement as if it didn't. I'm really confused as to why this is happening. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the complete code please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We appreciate the effort to try to show a short version of your code, but this example is TOO short. Please read [these guidelines](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Chances are, you don't have the same string in there twice, you have two strings that just look very similar.

Comment: `ArrayList.contains` should work, it is more likely you are doing something incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(!outputted.contains(string)){etc...}
```

The body of the if statement above will only execute if the String is NOT in the ArrayList. What you might want to do is try the same if condition but without the `!` like so:

```
if(outputted.contains(string)){etc...}
```

However without the rest of your code its difficult to tell if that really is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why you need to check contains?**

Better you can use `HashSet`.

Example code:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();
hashSet.addAll(arrayList);
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(hashSet);
```